# Node/Express trouble out of the box

Tags: node.js, macos, express

I just installed Node and Express for a tutorial I'm working on. When I try to run my server.js I get this. What's wrong? I know how to read the backtrace, but I didn't want to go mucking around in Express when it seems to me that it should be pristine, having just been installed.

```
example_app/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:47
  var opts = Object.create(options || null)
                ^

TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: /
  at Function.create (native)
  at Function.serveStatic [as static] (/Users/blahblah/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/example_app/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:47:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/blahblah/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/example_app/server.js:4:23)
  at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
  at startup (node.js:136:18)
  at node.js:963:3
```

Here is the server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));

app.get('/customers/:id', function(req, res) {
    var customerId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var data = {};
    for (var i=0,len=customers.length;i<len;i++) {
        if (customers[i].id === customerId) {
           data = customers[i];
           break;
        }
    }
    res.json(data);
});

app.get('/customers', function(req, res) {
    res.json(customers);
    //res.json(500, { error: 'An error has occurred!' });
});

app.get('/orders', function(req, res) {
    var orders = [];
    for (var i=0,len=customers.length;i<len;i++) {
        if (customers[i].orders) {
            for (var j=0,ordersLen=customers[i].orders.length;j<ordersLen;j++) {
                orders.push(customers[i].orders[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    res.json(orders);
});

app.delete('/customers/:id', function(req, res) {
    var customerId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var data = { status: true };
    for (var i=0,len=customers.length;i<len;i++) {
        if (customers[i].id === customerId) {
           customers.splice(i,1);
           data = { status: true };
           break;
        }
    }
    res.json(data);
});

app.listen(8080);

console.log('Express listening on port 8080');
```

Comment: Could you put your `server.js` code in your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));
```

It should be:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

If you want to append a subdirectory, you can use this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

Just so you're aware, you're using a deprecated version of Express :)